# How can I tell whether push notification is not registered yet or has been turned off?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

More specificly, I want to know if the push notification settings for my app are available in the Settings App.
If they are available, I want to open it from my app (using deep link).
I they are not, I want to ask the user to register for push notifications in my app.

I tried checking `UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`, but it returned false for both cases.
I need to support iOS 9 and above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need permission to register for remote notifications; you can just do it.

What you do need permission for is to *display notifications*.  The permission request is the same, whether you want to display local or remote notifications.

Comment: Looking at push notification guides such as the [official](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1) and from [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) ,  requesting permissions comes first using `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization`. Do you mean there is a way to make push notification settings available in Settings App before doing this?

Comment: Requesting first makes sense, since you may not bother registering for notifications if the user doesn't give permission, but you can still receive silent notifications if you have registered but not requested permission to display anything. Note the method you are using is*Registered*ForRemoteNotifications - it is about whether you have registered, not about permissions.  You check permissions to display notifications using `UNUserNotificationCenter`

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea! I’m on a vacation this week and it might be till next week to try it out.